# Bash: How can I name gs output files like the input files, but with a different file extension?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-processing, ghostscript

I have a lot of postscript (`.ps`) files in a single directory with names such as

```
cct@TOP_VMAIN_AND_3V3_SMPS,smps_ota,schematic.ps
```

that I want to batch convert to `.png` files

I already have the following command (using bash):

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -sOutputFile=out-%d.png *.ps
```

which is OK, but, obviously, it just outputs `out-1.png`, `out-2.png`
and so on, which means I don't know which `.png` came from which `.ps`.

What I want to do is be able to retain the filenames such 
that

```
cct@TOP_VMAIN_AND_3V3_SMPS,smps_ota,schematic.ps
```

gets converted to

```
cct@TOP_VMAIN_AND_3V3_SMPS,smps_ota,schematic.png
```

for each file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's parameter expansion:

```
f="cct@TOP_VMAIN_AND_3V3_SMPS,smps_ota,schematic.ps"
echo "${f%.*}.png"  # Remove everything after the last dot.
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a loop so that you get the single file names:

```
for psf in *.ps; do 
    pngf="`basename $psf`.png"; 
    gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -sOutputFile="$pngf" "$psf"
done
```

This is untested though. It's also slower, especially for many small files, because ghostscript is restarted over and over again. It's likely that one could construct something along the lines of feeding input to gs running in the background through pipes, and redirecting the output of the same running process via pipes to different files, but that seems difficult (how can I tell that ghostscript has finished a job?) and overkill.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The script by Peter does the job just nice.